# Несколько писем при отправке формы на почту

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Имеется такая форма. Письма приходят, всё хорошо. Но если при отправке формы нажать на кнопку "Отправить" несколько раз, то придет сразу несколько писем. Как избежать этого.
Пробовал event.stopPropagation() и event.stopImmediatePropagation(), ничего не помогает

```js
$('.callme-form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'mail.php',
    data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert('Thanks');
  });
});
```

```css
.callme-form {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

input,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background: #2e2e2b;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.btn-submit {
  width: 100%;
  color: #161613;
  background-color: #ffba00;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 54px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
}

i {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

label {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  transition: 0.28s ease;
}

span {
  color: #ffba00;
}

input+label,
textarea+label {
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

input:focus+label,
textarea:focus+label {
  display: none;
}

input:invalid,
input:valid {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="callme-form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="name-subscribe" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Имя">
    
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="tel" id="phone-field" name="phone" required="required" placeholder="Телефон">
    
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comment-field"></textarea>
    
  </div>
  <div class="aligncenter">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `disabled` Не ?

Comment: doox911, подробнее можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sending = false;
$('.callme-form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (sending)
    return;

  sending = true;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'mail.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    complete: function(){
      sending = false;
    }
  }).done(function() {
    alert('Thanks');
  });
});
```